# Tomcat Memory Spikes

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, tomcat7

We are running jdk 1.7.80 version with tomcat 7.0.62 version in production environment...

We had some high CPU Utilization in the past so we decided to increase tomcat Memory to 10 g xmx and xmx is 2Gb..

After a day , we saw the process was consuming 3GB and CPU was not that busy in a minute the memory spiked to 11GB .. And tomcat has crashed.. we don't see any out of memory errors in catatina.out or other errors ..It happened twice after increasing the memory..

I have run some memory leak diagnostics but didn't find any potential issue. . even if it's a memory leak won't should slowly increase and crash? It spikes in less than a minute ..

Tried getting heapdump using jmap but it was very slow since our env can't be down for more time.. planning to monitor using jmx ..

Can GC pause can cause to memory spike?

But do anyone have faced similar issue.. ideas and suggestions would really help

Comment: Install some proper monitoring of the cpu/memory that you can compare with the traffic / time of day.  Setup tomcat to auto-restart if the memory use is too high.  Plan to update to use a new version of tomcat and java

Comment: Thanks fr your reply.. If you're aware of any proper monitoring for production environments let me know... Jmx port can be used in production? Will tat cause any performance issue

Comment: Most of the java agent based (unfortunately paid) solutions doesn't affect the performance that much to be an issue. We have our production constantly under inspection.

Comment: Can you post which GC you are using and flags you are using to start tomcat.  While none of the GCs will cause a memory spike, they do cause CPU spikes especially CMS, while G1 is a lot more frequent and easier on the cpu.  A memory spike often means there may be a loop allocating memory (due to a bug possibly).  Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html specifically the  -XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag.  99.9999% of the time the bug is in your code and not the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your post @AlexC , We use UseParallelOldGC while starting tomcat as service. I suspect it causes CPU spike first and then impacts memory, , I will look at the url and try out the options in production,

Comment: Think about using G1 garbage collector it's the best at this point from my experience and default with Java 8+

Comment: @Gokulakrishnan did u find any solution regarding this issue i m also having same issue.